# Get the received message from the sender to a specific controller : MassTransit in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, rabbitmq, microservices, masstransit

I am quite new in Masstransit and rabbitMq and I want to establish a communication between two Web APIs.

**The goal**: if the `service A` receive a request to make something but the it needs some additional information from another `service B`, I want to make this connection between the two services using Masstransit and RabbitMq, but I want to get the returned result from the service B in the action method in the specific controller in service A (the API that requested the information).

I already created the integration of Masstransit and RabbitMq, but I am getting the message in the consumer and I want get that result in the action method that is waiting for the response from the service B.

If there are any examples or any hint to adapt the solution or anything may help that would very appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the request client to generate a request, and get the response. An example in an API controller is shown in the [scoped filter](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-ScopedFilters/blob/master/src/WebApi/Controllers/CheckInventoryController.cs#L16) sample, along with many other of the MassTransit samples.

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class CheckInventoryController :
    ControllerBase
{
    readonly IRequestClient<CheckInventory> _client;

    public CheckInventoryController(IRequestClient<CheckInventory> client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string sku)
    {
        Response<InventoryStatus> response = await _client.GetResponse<InventoryStatus>(new {sku});

        return Ok(response.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks that was helpful , but in dev case that works but what about  when the app receive  thousands of request or if the services where deployed in different environnements  ? would that make any differnece , and how the injection of the client works ?

Comment: It works, and it scales. The [request configuration](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/requests.html#request-client-configuration) is documented. And you should use a different broker instance for each environment.